# Hibernate Query : Order By time difference

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql, hql, criteria

Can one write HQL as well as Hibernate query syntax using criteria or generalDao of google api

```
SELECT id,
   CASE WHEN from_time > current_timestamp THEN (from_time - current_timestamp) 
        ELSE (current_timestamp - from_time) 
               END as a
FROM meetings order by a;
```

Comment: Take a look at following link: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions. This might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [CASE in your HQL queries](http://www.benashby.com/spring/2013/09/16/case-clause-in-hibernate-select.html).
2. Instead of current_timestamp you should use the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() function, that's also supported by HQL.